# Negative representation of Perl hex number is always sign-extended to 8 bytes

Tags: perl, hex, printf

I am using `sprintf` in Perl to convert decimal numbers to their hex equivalents, as in:

```
my $positive = sprintf("X'%02X'", 1);   # X'01'
my $negative = sprintf("X'%02X'", -1);  # X'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

Why does the negative number always get sign-extended to the 8-byte representation of the number, even if the precision specified in `sprintf` is smaller?

Is there a way to avoid this so I don't have to substring the value every time? The same result occurs even if I remove the `0`, as in: `sprintf("X'%2X'", -1)`.

Comment: What exact characters to you want generated for the value -1?

Comment: I was hoping to get `FF` with the precision of 2 (for a final result of `X'FF'`) but as Brian explained, `%x` expects an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `%x` specifically takes an unsigned integer, so when you give it the bit pattern for a signed integer, it treats all of those bits as an unsigned one. The length of the output probably depends on how big your compiler made numbers (although I'm guessing most modern things are the same now). Perl stores most of its numbers as doubles, so that's the size of the number. It's one of few places where Perl exposes the underlying architecture.

This means that you need to handle the sign yourself and use the absolute value of the number:

```
sprintf(  "%s%2x", ($n < 0 ? '-' : ''), abs($n) );
```

As for the [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf) field specifiers, you are not specifying a precision there. That's minimum width. The `%f` and `%g` specifiers may have a maximum number of decimal places, but the entire string can still overflow.

But, it turns out that your problem is different. You want the values from -128 to 127 it their signed integer form. So, -1 gets `FF`. You need to add a little bit to get that.

```
my $s = sprintf( "%2x", $n );
$s = substr( $s, -2 ) if $n < 0;
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants `sprintf("X'%02X'", $n & 0xFF)`

Comment: Well, that breaks when the negative number has a magnitude larger than the mask.

Comment: Thank you both. @ikegami yes, ideally I'd like it to just be `X'FF'` without the actual sign. Since that does break under certain conditions as Brian mentioned, I can fiddle with it or just substring the returned value from `sprintf` as needed. It's not a huge deal since this is just for a small script I'm writing to generate tables whose values won't change.

Comment: @briandfoy except I don't think their input is outside of -128..127

Comment: Whose output? The OP or anyone else in the world who reads this trying to solve a different problem?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this issue for myself. Seems like printing byte data in hexadecimal format is pretty fundamental and sprintf should support that well, but instead even 'C' sprintf has issues dealing with unsigned values since it expects a signed int. The case with perl is similar (as described in @brian-d-foy answer):

```
printf("%.2hhx", $byte);
```

or

```
printf("%02hhx", $byte);
```

Will print just the 2 hexadecimal values as desired.

This is a departure from the 'C' implementation of sprintf, and the 'hh' seems to be missing from some copies of perl sprintf documentation, so perhaps is relatively new.

> **size**
>
> ```
> For numeric conversions, you can specify the size to interpret the number as using l, h, V, q, L, or ll
> ```

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf

In the OPs case:

```
sprintf("X'%02hhX'", -1) eq "X'FF'"
```